# .Net 6 pass array in query string

Tags: data-binding, query-string, .net-6.0

I have an issue with passing string array in query string and I don't know what's happening. here is the request:

```
.../api/customers/todos?customerValue=0&branchId=120&allianceId=1&searchValue=&offset=0&count=14&statuses=one&statuses=two&statuses=three
```

and this is my method:

```
 public async Task<PaginatedResult<TodoVm>> GetTodos(decimal? customerValue, string branchId, 
            long? allianceId, string searchValue,
            string[] statuses = null,
            int offset = 0, int count = 20)
        {
            //do some stuff and return response
        }
```

when I call the api it gives me this error and cannot bind the `statues` parameter:

```
{
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "errors": {
        "$": [
            "The input does not contain any JSON tokens. Expected the input to start with a valid JSON token, when isFinalBlock is true. Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0."
        ]
    }
}
```

but when I use `FromQuery` it works! like this:

```
 public async Task<PaginatedResult<TodoVm>> GetTodos(decimal? customerValue, string branchId, 
            long? allianceId, string searchValue,
            [FromQuery(Name = "statuses")] string[] statuses = null,
            int offset = 0, int count = 20)
        {
            //do some stuff and return response
        }
```

other parameters will be mapped correctly but for array I have to use `FromQuery`.

FYI, this is how I add controller in `Startup`:

```
services.AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = false;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
                options.JsonSerializerOptions.AllowTrailingCommas = false;
            });
```

**The Answer:**

I figured it out that in asp.net core Arrays are treated as **body** parameters in [ApiController] so for binding array values so you need to specify `[FromQuery]`.